# Closing the form does not closing the Application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms in my c# windows project . The first form is called is called "loginform" and the other one is called "mainform" . I want to move to the mainform on button click But when i reached at the mainform , the problem is when i tries to close my second form which is named "mainform" here ,  the application does not close and i have to use the visual studio to terminate the project. below is the code for moving to second form

```
        this.Hide();
        mainform mf = new mainform();
        mf.Show();
```

Comment: In you have two top level, non-modal forms, either one can keep the app open. If you want either one to close the app, keep track of the two form instance somewhere and call a method  as each form is closing (in the FormClosing handler) that checks if each form is open, and, if it is, call Form.Close on it

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. On the second form add the following code on the formclosed event .

```
 private void mainform_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.ExitThread();
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps could you explain what you solution is? Just in case someone in the future has the same problem :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is because “your code” basically “throws away” ANY reference back to `this` when the code sets it as “hidden”…

```
this.Hide();
```

After this line of code is executed, `mainform` is created and shown…

```
mainform mf = new mainform();
mf.Show();
```

Assuming, there is no code “after” the code above… then basically `this` has now been lost. The user can NOT see the form nor interact with it. `mainform` is shown… but it knows nothing about `this`. `this` is now lost and you have NO way of getting it back. That’s why it keeps running.

Obviously, `mainform` has no idea about `this` i.e. … the form that “created” it, however it DOES need `this` to stay alive. IF we “close” `this` and `this` created `mainform`… then `mainform` depends on `this` and will also close when `this` closes.

```
mainform mf = new mainform();
mf.Show();
this.Close();
```

Then, `mainform` gets killed as soon a `this` closes. So that will not work. However… if you changed the `Show` to `ShowDialog`… for the `mf.ShowDialog()`, then it would work and `this` would get closed properly.

Therefore, IF you want to “CLOSE” the form that “created” another form, then you should spin off another process for the `mainform` or pass `this` to the `mainform` and let it close it when it is done. I am sure there are other ways to do this and if `Application.ExitThread();` ... works for you then go for it.

Comment: can You pls share a link ??

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something. Is there some part of what I described that is not clear? When you execute … `this.Hide()` … then… the form is not seen by the user. Without some “external” mechanism to “un-hide” the form so you can close it properly… then it basically becomes “inaccessible” from that point on. This is why you are having to use… `Application.ExitThread();`.

Comment: I suggest you change `Show` to `ShowDialog` and add `this.Close();` as the last line. I am just saying, that the problem is that the first form is not getting closed. At least with this approach, the user will eventually close `mainform` and that will execute the `this.Close()`.